# JQuery Function on link click

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to call up a jquery function on link click with no success:

here is my html:

```
<a href="..." id="removeItem" checkID="12" >Delete</a>
<a href="..." id="removeItem" checkID="13" >Delete</a>
<a href="..." id="removeItem" checkID="14" >Delete</a>

    $("#removeItem").click(function(checkID) {
    return false;
    var checkID = $(this).attr("checkID");
    $("#removeDialog").dialog( {
        buttons: {
            "No" : function () {
                $(this).dialog("destroy");
                $('input#CheckName').focus();
            },
            "Yes": function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "itemRemoveWS.html?id=checkID",
                    data: {
                        "action" : "remove",
                        "id" : checkID
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#removeDialog").dialog("destroy");
                        var ang = '';
                        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                        $.each(obj, function() {
                           ang += '<table class="form"><tr><td width="45">' + this["CheckID"] + '</td><td width="140">' + this["Name"] + '</td><td width="95">' + this["CheckNumber"] + '</td><td align="right" width="70">$' + this["Amount"] + '</td><td width="220" style="padding-left: 15px;">' + this["Description"] +'</td><td><a href="#">Delete</a></td></tr></table>';
                        });
                        $('#container').html(ang);
                        $("input#Amount").val('');
                        $("input#CheckName").val('');
                        $("input#Check_Number").val('');
                        $("select#Company").val('MMS');
                        $("th#dept").hide();
                        $('input#CheckName').focus();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have `return false;` as first instruction in your click event callback function. This means you are doing nothing.

Put it at the very last line of your logic or better change it to `e.preventDefault();`  using

```
$("#removeItem").click(function(e) {...}
```

As a side note, `$("#removeItem").click(function(checkID) {}`  checkID will be an ref to triggered event here, not an element id attribute.

And again, ID attribute MUST be unique for each element on each html page.

Answer (score 2):

To call of function on a link click use javascript:void(0) as your href, then add your function call to the onclick event of your link:

```
<a runat="server" id="myButton" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction();" ></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `return false`, do this:

```
checkID.preventDefault();
```

Also, you're not allowed to have two elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

As roasted said, return false is likely your issue. It may be that you meant this:

```
checkID.preventDefault();
```